# As a cryptographer, what are the things I should care about in my implementation of pairing functions?

Tags: elliptic-curves, implementation, pairings

As a beginner in cryptography, I do not know anything about different pairing types more than their names. So far, I know these names: Ate pairing, tate pairing, eta pairing, and r-ate pairing.

I am curious whether I should care which type of pairing I am using in my implementations? Do they affect performance or security at all?

What should I know about these types?

So far, I think I've got these points:

1. There is an obvious and serious difference between different types of **"Curve Generation"** in pairings. I mean, whether they are Super Singular, MNT curves, Cocks-Pinch, Barreto-Naehrig, etc is really important because it affects the "security multiplier" (i.e. embedding rate). And for a certain security parameter higher embedding rate means better performance and shorter representation of elements of $G_1$.
2. Also it is important whether the curves are over **"large prime fields"** or over fields of **"small characteristic"** because [recent research works in cryptanalysis of elliptic curves show that elliptic curves over fields of small characteristic are not secure anymore](http://ellipticnews.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/new-discrete-logarithm-records-and-the-death-of-type-1-pairings/).

Comment: On number 2, can you give a citation? I know there has been work that broke the DL problem for finite fields of small characteristic, but that work doesn't apply to ECDLP.

Comment: @pg1989, I cite the blog post by Steven Galbraith who is, to my knowledge, one of the most well-known researchers in the topic of Elliptic Curves. He apparently indicates that the curves on small characteristics are dead and so the the Type-I pairings because these pairings on fields of large primes are practically inefficient.

Comment: @pg1989, an interesting question and answer on crypto.SE related to this topic is [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15868/is-pairing-based-cryptography-ready-for-productive-use)

Comment: I wonder is there a problem with my explanation of question or it is not a matter of interest for the majority of this website's users. I expected much more interested and experienced users in this field. I can't believe there was no answer during these days. (And... am I allowed to post this type of comments?)

Comment: In my opinion the question is too open-ended. You should ask specific questions about specific aspects of pairing implementations. Also pairings are a new and complex primitive that are still pretty niche. Also, you could ask the author of [PBC](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/) this in an email.