# Does pairings based cryptography inherently require a CRS/trusted setup?

Tags: algorithm-design, pairings, group-theory

In all algorithms I've seen that rely on pairings-based cryptography (some examples: [snarks without PCPs](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-38348-9_37), [more snarks](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-40084-1_6), [sublinear ring signatures](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-73420-8_38)), a common reference string is required. Is this always the case? If so, what is it about pairings (or the algorithms that use them?) that means the CRS is needed?

I know ZCash got around this by using MPC to emulate a TTP as described [here](https://z.cash/technology/paramgen.html), [here](https://z.cash/blog/generating-zcash-parameters.html), and [here](https://z.cash/downloads/mpc_whitepaper.pdf), but I'm more interested in understanding why the CRS is necessary. To clarify, I don't mean why the party that generates it needs to be trusted, as I understand that the public parameters of the CRS cannot be generated without use of the 'private' component that must later be destroyed, but I would like to know *why* the public parameters are required?

(I've looked at [is pairing based crypto ready for productive use](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15868/is-pairing-based-cryptography-ready-for-productive-use) thinking it might answer this question but it doesn't)

Answer (score 5):

No. For example, these pairing-based protocols don't require trusted setup:

- BLS signatures;
- tripartite Diffie-Hellman, as mentioned in Elias' answer;
- some identity-based encryption schemes (when users are their own PKGs, e.g. when using IBE for forward-secure encryption);
- the [Bünz–Maller–Mishra–Vesely](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1177) polynomial commitment scheme. (This could in principle be used for NIZK arguments of knowledge, although it has $\Theta(\sqrt{N})$ verification and so is not fully succinct.)

Answer (score 3):

The introductory example for the use of pairings is [tripartite Diffie-Hellman](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=749894) key exchange with a single message by Joux.

It requires no trusted party or CRS.

This nature of allowing a DH like interaction between 3 parties is the reason why many of the TTP setups work with pairings. It's used for the third party.