# What pairings are used in PBC and charm-crypto with the proposed elliptic curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings

I'm implementing a pairing-based signature scheme using [Charm Crypto](https://jhuisi.github.io/charm/toolbox/pairinggroup.html) and [PBC](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/manual/), and I'm struggling to understand the relationship between the curves proposed for use with pairings and the pairings themselves.

As I understand it, I can choose between various curves (e.g. I would like to use [TypeD](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/manual/ch08s06.html) curves).

I know that there are different pairings such as the Weil, Tate, Eta and Ate pairing. I also read something about a classification in [pairing types](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15868/is-pairing-based-cryptography-ready-for-productive-use/15869#15869). So, MNT (TypeD) curves are useful for Type 3 pairings - or do they define Type 3 pairings? What is the relation to Tate / Ate / Eta pairings? And knowing that, how do I find which specific pairings are used with TypeD curves in Charm?